# Is there a way to press webpage button fast without rendering the page

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

So recently, I tried to use selenium to load a website in a browser, navigate to a button and click it, then closing the driver and starting over again (To clear cache)
I got it to click about once every 5 seconds per active script i had open, most of the time going into actually restarting the browser driver and loading the webpage

Later though, I found out somebody else was clicking the same button roughly 5 times per second, which I could simply not achieve.
Is there a way to load and click the buttons with Python, without rendering or reloading the website / driver?

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium import webdriver
import selenium
from time import sleep

while 1:
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    driver.get("*****")
    xpath2 = "//*[@id=\"main\"]/div[1]/div/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div/a/div/div/button"
    elem2 = driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath2)
    sleep(0.2)
    try:
        elem2.click()
    except:
        pass
    sleep(0.2)
    try:
        xpath = "//*[@id=\"CybotCookiebotDialogBodyLevelButtonLevelOptinAllowAll\"]"
        elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath)
        elem.click()
    except:
        pass
    sleep(0.2)
    try:
        elem2.click()
    except:
        try:
            driver.close()
        except:
            pass
    sleep(0.2)
    driver.close()
```

That's my code by the way, the reason for the try and excepts is because of a cookie message loading at different times, and i need to call the button press on the actual button twice because it cant click on it the first time since its not clickable at that moment

Comment: are you trying to say that you would want to be able to click the element as soon as it appears and not waiting for website to load fully?

Comment: Well I want the script to simply press or trigger a button and its action on a website as fast as possible, or with the least resource usage and error capability as possible, so that in that case it can be run a lot of times. Also it should consume a minimum amount of bandwidth

Comment: why is your `driver = webdriver.Chrome()` within the while loop? this will open a new browser every time. Is this intentional?

Comment: Yes it is intentional, as without doing that the cache of the browser session is kept. The button tracks if you have already pressed it once meaning that I need to clear the entire browsers data inbetween

Answer (score 0):

You may use `pageLoadStrategy` to make page clickable as soon as that certain element appears to click it without having to wait for full website to load, and then proceed to the next website.

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

caps = DesiredCapabilities().CHROME
# caps["pageLoadStrategy"] = "normal"  #  Waits for full page load
caps["pageLoadStrategy"] = "none"   # Do not wait for full page load
driver = webdriver.Chrome(desired_capabilities=caps)

while True:
    driver.get('url to the website')

    xpath = "xpath to the element"
   # clicking on the element as soon as it appears
    element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
                EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, xpath2))
            )
    element.click()

   # rest of the logic goes here
    
driver.close()
```

Comment: @konstanius-eu was this any helpful for you?